# Continuing a BASH script after error

Tags: bash, http-status-code-404, wget

This script works well in finding what I need, but there are occassions where a 404 error just kills everything.

```
#!/bin/sh
 set +e

 exec 7<foo.txt
 exec 8<bar.tmp

 echo "Retrieving data"

 while read line1 <&7 && read line2 <&8
 do

 echo "beginning... retrieving files from d list"
 echo "this WILL take a while"

 echo $line1
 echo $line2


 wget -e  robots=off -t1 -r -p -Q20k --wait=30 --random-wait --limit-rate=200k -np -U "$line1"  http://$line2/page.html

 cp /home/user/testing/*.html /home/user/production

 echo "done"
 done

 exec 7<&-
 exec 8<&-
```

I want to continue the script because even though this site, known as $line2 has a 404, the others don't.

I have done the "set +e", and even ran the script with "|| true", all stopping after the error. Because of the 404, there are no files to copy - and then it fails to go onto the next site.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This script should not be stopping on error. If it writes "done" after the 404 error and then stops, it's because of your input files. Please include the complete output

Comment: If `wget` is the command that has the non-zero exit status, *it* is the one that needs `|| true` put after it: `wget ... || true`. Better yet, consider ditching `set +e` and do your own error handling.

Comment: Whoa, I have never seen that `exec` shell redirection construct. That is kinda cool.

Comment: But `set +e` *disables* errexit

Comment: What I found works is this:  'code'    if [ ! -d "/home/user/production" ]; then
  continue           #continue the loop.
   fi
'/code'

Answer (score 0):

What I found works is this:

```
if [ ! -d "/home/user/production" ]; then
    continue           #continue the loop.
fi
```